# Is it possible to add hash in admin menu link using config.xml?

Tags: magento

I have the following configuration for an admin menu item. I would like the menu item link to include a hash to directly go to the appropriate group.

```
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <theme module="theme" translate="title">
            <title>Theme</title>
            <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
            <children>
                <configuration module="theme" translate="title">
                    <title>Configuration</title>
                    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/design</action>
                </configuration>
            </children>
        </theme>
    </menu>
<adminhtml>
```

E.g. I would like to have a link to

```
adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/design#theme
```

Is this possible using config.xml? If not, what would be the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top menu URL's are built using this code:

```
Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->getUrl((string)$child->action, array('_cache_secret_key' => true)
```

This means it is not possible to add additional parameters or a anchor to the generated URL.

Possible solutions would include rewriting the block class `adminhtml/page_menu` and evaluating an additional tag, e.g. called `<params>`.
Another possibility would be to use JavaScript to rewrite the URL for that link.

Answer (score 0):

I think better solution would be simple redirection instead of rewriting core files or JavaScript. Simply add url that redirect to desired page with params:

adminhtml.xml: `<action>mymodule/adminhtml_controller/redirecttoproduct</action>`

In your contoller file:

```
public function redirecttoproductAction(){
    return $this->_redirect('adminhtml/catalog_product/edit', array(
        'id' => 168,
        'tab' => 'product_info_tabs_group_95'
    ));
}
```